# firebaserealtimedatabase version data saving error

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am saving data in firebase but some values are like this version 1.0 as firebase child app crashes due to not saving in the firebase. i am also converting values to string but still app crashes and not saving these values

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users")
                  .child("user")
                    .child(versioncodes).setValue(versioncodes);
```

version code like this version 1.0

Please tell how to resolve it

Comment: Adding crash log is more helpful to answer !

Comment: i have never used log. but the error is due to Value of firebase child that is (version 1.0) so please tell me how can i check child is suitable of adding to firebase or not

Comment: I'm not getting you properly !
Did you get successes in using another values ???
If not you might be set upped firebase properly !

Comment: ok i am clearing to you properly...i am storing some values in the firebase. my values contains (1.0) like this point values. so in the child we can not store these values in the firebase so the app crashes, so tell me how can i store these values in the firebase or add a condition so that if any value not stored in firebase it will not crash the app (Skip that value to store or change that value to suitable format)

Comment: what is the type versioncodes ? is it float or Float ? or something else ?

Comment: resolved bro added a condition to remove all special characters. Thanks

Comment: Ok ! But your requirement is to insert 1.0 which uses ( . ) character ?